# How do I use an attribute directive inside an element directive template in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, checklist-model

I have a need to show a list of check boxes on my site listing products and other items.  The checklist-model attribute directive works well for this because I can bind it to a list of items that relates to the items selected.

All this works fine when I simply use this code in my angular controller.  However, I have several list boxes that need to be displayed the same way with the same "select all" and "select none" buttons for each list.  I don't want to repeat this code and layout so I've created my own directive for the entire list.

The problem is when I use my own directive it doesn't bind correctly back to my data, the select all only works once, and the select none doesn't work at all.

I suspect it has something to do with how I'm passing the scope around, and the two directives are not working well together.

Why does this not work inside a directive?

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fande455/m9qhnr9c/7/

HTML

```
<section ng-app="myApp"   ng-controller="couponEditController">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="checkboxlist.template.html">
  <div>
    <div class="form-input form-list">
      <label ng-repeat="item in valuelist | orderBy:value">
        <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="model" checklist-value="item" /> {{item[value]}}
        <br />
      </label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-default" style="float:left; margin-bottom: 5px;margin-left: 10px;margin-right:10px" ng-click="selectNone()">Select None</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" style="float:left; margin-bottom: 5px;" ng-click="selectAll()">Select All</button>

    <div class="cleared"></div>
  </div>
</script>

<div>
  <checkboxlist model="coupon.Products" value="Name" valuelist="productsList"></checkboxlist>
</div>
</section>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['checklist-model']);

myApp.directive('checkboxlist', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'checkboxlist.template.html',
    controller: 'checkboxlistController',
    scope: {
      model: "=",
      value: "@",
      valuelist: "="
    },
    require: '^checklist-model'
  }
}]);

myApp.controller('checkboxlistController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.selectAll = function() {
    $scope.model = angular.copy($scope.valuelist);
  };

  $scope.selectNone = function() {
    $scope.model = [];
  };
}]);

myApp.controller('couponEditController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.coupon = 
    {"Id": 1,
    "Name": "My Coupon",
    "Products": []
    }
  ;

  $scope.productsList = [{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Product 1"
  }, {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Product 2"
  }];
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation:

> Instead of doing checklistModelList = [] it is better to do
>   checklistModelList.splice(0, checklistModelList.length)

In your code you should do

```
$scope.selectAll = function() {
    $scope.selectNone();
    $scope.model.push.apply($scope.model, $scope.valuelist);
};

$scope.selectNone = function() {
    $scope.model.length = 0;
};
```

Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m9qhnr9c/9/

The idea is not to replace the array with a new one, but modify only its elements.

Comment: That fixed it.  My question is why?  And also why did it work the way I had it when it wasn't inside a directive?

Comment: Because inside the directive was creating a new scope.